# Report type "json" not known

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio, phpcs

I'm a beginner to using visual studio code. After I installed phpcs, I got an error:

> "Report type "json" not known

and

> phpcs: Cannot read property 'length' of null

[image]

Comment: I got rid of the first error by updating PHP_CodeSniffer from pear (`pear install PHP_CodeSniffer`, not sure if it works for Windows). The package that comes with my distribution seems outdated.